# Java How to set librarypath and native path for a jar file

Tags: java, lwjgl

How do you set the librarypath and the native path for a jar file? I have been using jarsplice/jarmatey but I don't want to anymore. I have tried

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", gameFolder+"/lib/jars" + File.separator);
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", gameFolder+"/lib/natives" + File.separator);
```

Where gamefolder if the games directory where the jar site and also

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/lib/jars" + File.separator);
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", "/lib/natives" + File.separator);
```

and the two without file separator either and those don't work. I have also tried, since when my game gets ran by the launcher it executes the cmd line to run it, adding in the -D... to th cmd arguments like this:

```
String cmd = "java -jar "+gameFolder+"/progame.jar -Djava.library.path=/lib/jars -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath=/lib/natives";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

and same with

```
String cmd = "java -jar "+gameFolder+"/progame.jar -Djava.library.path="+gameFolder+"/lib/jars -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath="+gameFolder+"/lib/natives";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

And none of those work. Any help? The files are in the path and i have checked to see if the paths exists through the code and they do and whatever but I am sol in my eyes.

Comment: Any arguments after `-jar filename` are passed to the main class defined in your jar, thus `-Dfoo=bar` and other JVM options like `-cp` and `-Xms` are only effective if **to the left** of `-jar`.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I load the .jar outside of my environment

```
public static void load()
{
    String fileNatives = OperatingSystem.getOSforLWJGLNatives();
    System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "native" + File.separator + fileNatives);
}
```

and for checking what operating system the user is on

```
class OperatingSystem {

private static String system = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

public static String getOSforLWJGLNatives()
{
    if(system.startsWith("win"))
    {
        return "windows";
    }

    if(system.startsWith("mac"))
    {
        return "macosx";
    }

    if(system.startsWith("lin"))
    {
        return "linux";
    }

    if(system.startsWith("sol"))
    {
        return "solaris";
    }
    return "unknown";
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand it completely. What does File.separator do?

Comment: the File.separator is just / or \ I believe its so it works on linux since they are opposite to other platforms

Comment: @user2819096 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you check if your gameFolder path contains a space caracter ? if so you should surround it with a double quote like

```
String cmd = "java -jar " +" \"" +gameFolder+"/progame.jar" +"\"" +" -Djava.library.path="+"\"" +gameFolder+"/lib/jars" +"\"" + " -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath="+"\"" +gameFolder+"/lib/natives"+"\"";
```

Comment: My gamefolder path is `/home/ty/progame`. it is basically a users home folder with the `progame` at the end of it. It also works in other parts of the code.