# Add --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED in Docker file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this Docker configuration:

```
# Use a Java runtime as the base image
FROM openjdk:21-slim-buster

VOLUME /tmp

# Copy the built JAR file into the container
ADD build/libs/engine.jar engine.jar

# Expose the default port for the app
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the app when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "engine.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/engine-configuration.yml", "--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"]
```

I tried to add `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` as Java VM argument but the configuration is not applied. Do you know how I can add this configuration as Java VM argument?

Comment: Does inserting `=` solve the issue i.e. `"--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"`?

Comment: No, it's not working

Comment: **Put it (at least) BEFORE `engine.jar`.** Arguments to the left of the classname, modulename, or jarname (as applicable) are passed to the JVM; arguments to the right are passed to the Java program's `main` method for it to handle -- or not. Some people prefer to keep `-jar`,`jarname` adjacent, although Java doesn't require it; if you do, put this or other JVM options before `-jar`.

Comment: Can you paste it as answer with complete example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Expanded to answer especially since I left out a related point.

**`--add-opens` is a JVM option and JVM options must go to the left of the classname, modulename, or jarname as applicable.** Arguments in that area are passed to the JVM and interpreted as options; arguments to the right of the class/module/jarname are passed to the Java program's `main` method for *it* to interpret and are not JVM options. Some people prefer to keep `-jar jarname` or `-m modulename` adjacent, and in that case put the other options like this one before the `-jar` or `-m`.

Also, you can use a single argument *with* the equal sign like `"--add-opens=blah"`, or TWO arguments like `"--add-opens","blah"`, but NOT a single argument with a space like `"--add-opens blah"`.

Thus any of:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED", "engine.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/engine-configuration.yml"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "--add-opens","java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED", "engine.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/engine-configuration.yml"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED", "-jar", "engine.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/engine-configuration.yml"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "--add-opens","java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED", "-jar", "engine.jar", "--spring.config.additional-location=file:/engine-configuration.yml"]
```

Effectively dupe
[Missing library on java.library.path trying to deploy executable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397296/missing-library-on-java-library-path-trying-to-deploy-executable-jar)
[Apache Tika parser not working in fat jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77196300/apache-tika-parser-not-working-in-fat-jar)
[Java How to set librarypath and native path for a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627213/java-how-to-set-librarypath-and-native-path-for-a-jar-file)
for a different JVM option (`-D`).